# HTML5 video tag on iPhone OS 3 is appearing outside a layer that has overflow: hidden;

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari, html5-video, ios3.0

I have an HTML5 video tag in a layer that has 'overflow: hidden;' set on it, but the video shows up outside the overflow area. It's essentially an accordion control, so the layer the video is in will be closed by default, and then when activated it will open up with a little slide down animation. Unfortunately, because the video isn't respecting the overflow property, the play button is always visible, and actually sits on top of other controls on the site. Does anyone know a way around this? I've tried adjusting z-index for the video tag, but without success.

Note: this seems to only be an issue with iPhone OS (or iOS) 3 and lower, as the new iOS 4 doesn't have this same problem.

Comment: Nope, it's in a DIV layer that has height: 0 and overflow: hidden

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that it's just not implemented in the old version. Occluding video results in quite a bit of extra processing (especially if the video decoding is hardware accelerated). If putting an absolutely positioned element on top of the video doesn't work either, I'd say you're just out of luck.

Why are you worrying about old versions by the way? Doesn't Apple push updates to their users properly? (I avoid Apple so I wouldn't know)

Comment: No, the update process is not automatic - so we still have to worry about iOS 3. The only thing automatic is that Apple will notify iOS users when a new OS is available the next time they sync their device with iTunes.

Comment: Also, for those with 1st gen iPhones, we cannot update to the new iOS